# While doing binary to hex conversions in java, my answers always have a null in front of them

Tags: java, eclipse

So my code works and outputs the correct answer however it gives me a null in the answer.

```
private void toHex() {
    char hexNum[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    String binary = num;

    if(binary.length() % 4 != 4) {
        while(binary.length() % 4 != 0) {
            binary = "0" + binary;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i+=4) {
        String temp2 = binary.substring(i, i+4);
        int sum = 0;
        sum += Integer.parseInt(temp2.charAt(0) + "")*8; 
        sum += Integer.parseInt(temp2.charAt(1) + "")*4; 
        sum += Integer.parseInt(temp2.charAt(2) + "")*2; 
        sum += Integer.parseInt(temp2.charAt(3) + "")*1; 
        hex = hex + hexNum[sum];
        sum = 0;
        temp2 = "";
    }
}
private void outHex() {
    System.out.print("Your number from binary to hexadecimal is: 0x" + hex);
    pw.print("Your number from binary to hexadecimal is: 0x" + hex);
}
```

Btw I declare num as a string outside the method and it is user inputted data. The hex is declared as a string outside the methods as well.

Comment: "I declare num as a string outside the method and it is user inputted data" — usually it's a pretty bad idea. Normally you'd define `String toHex(String binary)` and do not depend on variables from the outer scope.

Comment: Where is `hex` declared and initialized?

Comment: I declared hex right after the class outside all of the private methods. The user input is stored in an inputBin method which has a scanner and takes in num. The output I get look like this. 0110 becomes 0xnull6

Comment: It is not related to the issue but I believe the if-statement always evaluates to `true` because there will never be a remainder of 4 when dividing by 4.  You should be able to remove the if altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet you declared hex as.

```
String hex;
```

Which defaults to `null`.

Try the following:

```
String hex = "";
```

Which is an empty string.

Comment: Thank you. It worked when I set hex to an empty string.